# Does $\mathrm{PA}^-$ prove all true literal sentences of basic arithmetic?

Tags: logic

By "the literal sentences of basic arithmetic" let us mean sentences like

$$3+4=7,\;\; 2\cdot 3 = 3\cdot 2, \;\;S(2)=3$$

where for example $3$ is shorthand for $S(S(S(0)).$

Note that some literal sentences of basic arithmetic are true (e.g. $3+4=7$) while others are false (e.g. $2\cdot 3 = 1$).

Now let $\mathrm{PA}^-$ denote Peano arithmetic without induction. Does $\mathrm{PA}^-$ prove all **true** literal sentences of basic arithmetic?

Comment: What do you "exactly" mean about literal sentences? Only equalities of sums and products? Anything different?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis, precisely sentences of the form $x * y = z$ where the variables are stand-ins for numerals and $*$ is a stand-in for either $+$ or $\cdot$, and sentences of the form $S(x)=y.$

Comment: @MyUserIsThis, you have my apologies, but actually the comment I wrote above was silly and should be disregarded. It would be better to include sentences like $4+6=2\cdot(3+2).$

Comment: "Literal" is conventionally used in logic for atomic wffs *and* negated atomic wffs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This theory is called [Robinson arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) and the answer is yes assuming you mean sentences without quantifiers or variables.  There are some very simple quantified sentences that cannot be proved such as commutativity of addition ($\forall x, y: x + y = y + x$), although any instance of that such as $3 + 5 = 5 + 3$ can be.

Comment: Quick question: if we drop the axiom $x \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists y(x=S(y))$ from Robinson arithmetic, can all the literal sentences of basic arithmetic still be proved?

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure.

Comment: Usually, $\mathsf{PA}^-$ is taken to be a set of axioms for a discrete ordered semiring, rather than Robinson arithmetic.

Comment: @CarlMummert, thank you I was unaware of this convention.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Is Robinson's Q strictly weaker than PA$^-$ (discrete ordered semiring)? Rautenberg just says the former is interpretable in the latter but nothing else, and I could not find anything that answers my question.

Comment: @user21820: yes, it is much weaker; see a list of examples at the end of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/998914/630 . This is the 
main motivation for working with $PA^{-}$ instead, in some contexts. Robinson arithmetic is useful for some results in incompleteness, but not so much for studying models of fragments of Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Oh right; I'm not sure why I missed the fact that Q does not prove the basic ring properties. Thanks!